# Extract representative slope profiles from hillslope polygons

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology, grass.script, whitebox-gat, erosion

With the help of the [Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/tree/master/whitebox_tools) I was able to easily extract hill slopes from a river network in combination with a flow direction map.

Now I would like to extract representative slope profiles from each of this hill slopes. Representative slope profiles are 2D plots giving me the distance and elevation to the river for a representative flow line in a single hill slope.

I was wondering if there is already a open source tool for this since erosion models like 'WEPP' or 'Catflow' need this kind of input for modeling?

There are some toolboxes for ArcGIS but I would like to use open-source tools for several different reason.

Comment: What about using Whitebox GAT's Profile tool?

Comment: Thx for your answer. The problem with the profile tool is that a user needs to manually extract every 2d hillslope profile. In addition this can be very difficult because in some hillslopes finding the representative catena (2d profile) is not a standard task and to a wide part subjective to the editor. Therefore I used a approach from "Cochrane and Flanagan - Representiv hillslope methods for applying the WEPP model with a DEMs and GIS". I wrote the code in R. As soon as I have time to clean it , I could share it if someone is interested.

Comment: I can't say that I'm familiar with this method but would enjoy seeing your code when it is available.

Comment: I had time to clean up the code. If you write me your email I could send you the code with some example data for testing. It's based on modified version of the Cochrane and Flanagan (2003) approach by Francke et al. (2006).

Comment: My email address is at the bottom of the Profile tool's help if you'd like to send me your code. Thanks.